# How to apply proper error handling of TimeOut for httpclient

Tags: java

In my Xpages application I am calling an external service to collect data.

Users are complaining that they sometimes get a timeout error message:

Connect to customerbank.acme.se:20543 [customerbank.acme.se/127.17.27.172] failed: Connection timed out: connect

I assumed the timeout would result in an IOException but apparently not. How can I catch this error?

Below is part of my code. The logic of handling the response I have left out.

```
private CloseableHttpClient httpclient;

try{
    HttpClientBuilder cb = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                        .setSocketTimeout(30 * 1000)
                        .setConnectTimeout(30 * 1000)
                        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(30 * 1000)
                        .build();                   
    cb.setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig);
    httpclient = cb.build();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlFromConfiguration);
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    HttpEntity entity;
    entity = new ByteArrayEntity(JSONobj.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
    if (200 == response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()){//response received
        //perform some logic with the response... 
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    OpenLogUtil.logError(e);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new javax.faces.application.FacesMessage(javax.faces.application.FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "some IO exception occurred", ""));
} catch (Exception e) {
    OpenLogUtil.logError(e);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new javax.faces.application.FacesMessage(javax.faces.application.FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "some general error has occured" , ""));
}
```

Comment: *I assumed the timeout would result in an IOException* ... based on what documentation? In other words: don't assume things too quickly. Also note that it should be really easy to unit test/verify a bit of code like that.

Answer (score 1):

I think this [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-timeout) page can help you:

> "Note that the connection timeout will result in an
>   org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException being thrown, while
>   socket timeout will result in a java.net.SocketTimeoutException."

Answer (score 0):

Apache Http client that you are using is a great utility. But it could be a bit heavy and cumbersome for a relatively simple task that you are running. There is a much simpler Http client provided in MgntUtils Open source library (written by me). It may be not as comprehensive as Apache one, but is much simpler in use. It does throw IOException upon connection or time-out error. In your case it could be an alternative to use. Take a look at [Javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html). Library itself provided as [Maven artifacts](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.5.0.7/jar) and on [Git](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases/tag/1.5.0.7) (including source code and Javadoc). All in all your code may look like this:

```
private static void testHttpClient() {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.setContentType("application/json");
    String content = null;
    try {
        content = client.sendHttpRequest("http://yourUrl.com", HttpMethod.POST, JSONobj.toString());
        //content holds the response. Do your logic here
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //Error Handling is here
        content = TextUtils.getStacktrace(e, false);
    }
}
```